# How to apply OneColumnFullWidth section in SharePoint site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powershell, modern-experience, pnp

I have created a site template using PnP framework:

```
<pnp:Section Order="3" Type="OneColumnFullWidth">
              <pnp:Controls>
                <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;beb70bd5-7993-4b79-ad1b-2107dec09eb8&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;ed149dc0-5ae8-448b-a7a0-e5f519361804&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:6016,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:4016,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:620,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:6016,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:2028,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:false,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE9.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;ed149dc0-5ae8-448b-a7a0-e5f519361804&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:6016,&quot;height&quot;:4016,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:620,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:6016,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:2028}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="1" />
              </pnp:Controls>
            </pnp:Section>
            <pnp:Section Order="4" Type="ThreeColumn">
              <pnp:Controls>
                <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;af4e84a1-1d4f-45d0-94d9-6c1232271279&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;\n      a body of water\n    &quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;\n      Add your text here.\n    \n&quot;,&quot;fileName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;1730befb-02e2-440d-8239-6d1b7d44218e&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:5517,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:3702,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:12,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:5517,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:3678,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:true,&quot;isOverlayTextEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0,&quot;position&quot;:{&quot;offsetX&quot;:0,&quot;offsetY&quot;:0}}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE7.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;1730befb-02e2-440d-8239-6d1b7d44218e&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:5517,&quot;height&quot;:3702,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:12,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:5517,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:3678}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="1" />
                <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Text" ControlId="5db27991-a061-4a30-ab9e-bc856633208f" Order="2" Column="1">
                  <pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
                    <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="Text" Value="&lt;span class=&quot;fontSizeMediumPlus&quot;&gt;Above is an image with a text overlay. Click inside the image to replace the text with your own. &amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;" />
                  </pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
                </pnp:CanvasControl>
                <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;203e35f5-f398-40b0-b246-8e8c9a4e8b9d&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;\n      Add your text here.\n    \n&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;54b4930e-619d-48f5-85ad-0dde8f5aea3f&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:8832,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:4968,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:690,&quot;cropY&quot;:0,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:7452,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:4968,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:true,&quot;isOverlayTextEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0,&quot;position&quot;:{&quot;offsetX&quot;:0,&quot;offsetY&quot;:0}}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE2.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;54b4930e-619d-48f5-85ad-0dde8f5aea3f&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:8832,&quot;height&quot;:4968,&quot;cropX&quot;:690,&quot;cropY&quot;:0,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:7452,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:4968}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="2" />
                <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Text" ControlId="0a70cd50-c12d-4dd4-8fcc-f54ff8fdac5b" Order="2" Column="2">
                  <pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
                    <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="Text" Value="&lt;span class=&quot;fontSizeMediumPlus&quot;&gt;Above is an image with a text overlay. Click inside the image to replace the text with your own. &amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;" />
                  </pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
                </pnp:CanvasControl>
                <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;21d6dc70-e714-4990-992c-556f3c233e74&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;\n      Add your text here.\n    \n&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;d04aa0c8-0444-4f92-ba42-5601d9356b98&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:4608,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:3456,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:192,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:4608,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:3072,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:false,&quot;isOverlayTextEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0,&quot;position&quot;:{&quot;offsetX&quot;:0,&quot;offsetY&quot;:0}}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE10.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;d04aa0c8-0444-4f92-ba42-5601d9356b98&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:4608,&quot;height&quot;:3456,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:192,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:4608,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:3072}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="3" />
                <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Text" ControlId="d96d37c8-d729-46ae-9cf9-3f4c316ec88e" Order="2" Column="3">
                  <pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
                    <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="Text" Value="&lt;span class=&quot;fontSizeMediumPlus&quot;&gt;Above is an image with a text overlay. Click inside the image to replace the text with your own. &amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;" />
                  </pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
                </pnp:CanvasControl>
              </pnp:Controls>
            </pnp:Section>
            <pnp:Section Order="5" Type="OneColumnFullWidth">
              <pnp:Controls>
                <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="Image" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;aaa96f85-b30a-4927-a87f-7ebe7fdce9ed&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;\n      Image\n    &quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;\n      Show an image on your page\n    &quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.11&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;imageSourceType&quot;:2,&quot;altText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;overlayText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;f46ca4be-b168-4ef2-b91a-dbbde97d31af&quot;,&quot;imgWidth&quot;:4800,&quot;imgHeight&quot;:2696,&quot;isFullWidth&quot;:true,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:633,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:4800,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:1372,&quot;fixAspectRatio&quot;:false,&quot;captionText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;alignment&quot;:&quot;Center&quot;,&quot;overlayTextStyles&quot;:{&quot;textColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;isBold&quot;:false,&quot;isItalic&quot;:false,&quot;textBoxColor&quot;:&quot;dark&quot;,&quot;textBoxOpacity&quot;:0.54,&quot;overlayColor&quot;:&quot;light&quot;,&quot;overlayTransparency&quot;:0}}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:&quot;/_LAYOUTS/IMAGES/VISUALTEMPLATEIMAGE11.JPG&quot;},&quot;links&quot;:{},&quot;customMetadata&quot;:{&quot;imageSource&quot;:{&quot;siteId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;webId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;listId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;uniqueId&quot;:&quot;f46ca4be-b168-4ef2-b91a-dbbde97d31af&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:4800,&quot;height&quot;:2696,&quot;cropX&quot;:0,&quot;cropY&quot;:633,&quot;cropWidth&quot;:4800,&quot;cropHeight&quot;:1372}}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="d1d91016-032f-456d-98a4-721247c305e8" Order="1" Column="1" />
              </pnp:Controls>
            </pnp:Section>
          </pnp:Sections>
```

But I am getting following error while applying template

> You can't use a OneColumnFullWidth section in this site template GROUP

Please find code snippet I am using for apply template

```
static void ApplyProvisioningTemplate(string targetWebUrl, string userName, string pwdS)
        {
            SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in pwdS.ToCharArray()) pwd.AppendChar(c);
            var site = new Uri(targetWebUrl);
            if (GetContext(site, userName, pwdS, out var ctx))
            {
                using (ctx)
                {
                    // ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(userName, pwd);
                    //ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);
                    ctx.RequestTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;

                    Web web = ctx.Web;

                    ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation ptai = new ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation();
                    ptai.ProgressDelegate = delegate (String message, Int32 progress, Int32 total)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0:00}/{1:00} - {2}", progress, total, message);
                    };

                    // Associate file connector for assets
                    XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider connector = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(@"C:\temp\pnpprovisioningdemo", "");
                    // template.Connector = connector;
                    var template = connector.GetTemplate("PnPProvisioningDemo3.xml");
                    // Because the template is actual object, we can modify this using code as needed
                    //template.Lists.Add(new ListInstance()
                    //{
                    //    Title = "PnP Sample Contacts",
                    //    Url = "lists/PnPContacts",
                    //    TemplateType = (Int32)ListTemplateType.Contacts,
                    //    EnableAttachments = true
                    //});

                    web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(template, ptai);
                }
            }
        }
```

Why I am getting the above error? Is there anyway to `onecolumnfullwidth` to work in .net core? I am ready to migrate to another package or framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation by Microsoft, you cannot use full-width column layout in SharePoint team sites.

> **Note** Full-width column is not available on pages that are part of Team sites. It is available only on pages that are part of Communication sites.

**Documentation**: [Add sections and columns on a SharePoint modern page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/add-sections-and-columns-on-a-sharepoint-modern-page-fc491eb4-f733-4825-8fe2-e1ed80bd0899)

You are receiving this error as you are trying to create a site template with `GROUP` - which is for SharePoint **team site** connected with Microsoft 365 group.

If you want to create a page section with full-width column layout, you will have to use the template for SharePoint communication site (`SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0`).